# why it is fine to add question mark inside a generics brackets but not for method parameter?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, generics, overriding

In Kotlin, I can't understand if we can add **?** when overriding a class or a method.
For example the following code:

```
    class BaseAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

If i add a **?** inside <>, after **RecyclerView.ViewHolder**, the code will be compiled.

**But**, if i add a **??** after **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** in *onBindViewHolder* function, it says that:

> The Method Overrides nothing

and code isn't being compiled.

I can't understand why when adding it inside **<>** it's ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the type of the `holder` parameter for `onBindViewHolder` is defined as non-null in the class you are extending. It's defined in Java, so it uses an annotation for defining the nullability:

```java
public abstract void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position);
```

So it doesn't matter if the class type is a non-nullable or a nullable type. The method parameter is defined as the non-nullable version of whatever the class type is.

It doesn't matter if you define the type as nullable or not for the `Adapter` class.

If `RecyclerView.Adapter` were defined in Kotlin, they probably would have marked the class type as having to be non-null, but that can't be done with Java annotations. I think that would be the only way to create this same restriction on the method parameter nullability in Kotlin.

Comment: can you please explain what did you mean in the last paragraph that starts with the word "if" and end with the work "Kotlin"? especially the last sentence: * I think that would be the only way to create this same restriction on the method parameter nullability in Kotlin*. I didn't understand it at all

Comment: If you are composing a class in Kotlin that requires some generic type parameter to be non-null, you would have to mark it as non-nullable at the declaration site. For instance, in this case you would have `class Adapter<VH: ViewHolder>` instead of `class Adapter<VH: ViewHolder?>`. If you declared it the second way, there would be no clear way for you to mark a function parameter as the non-null version of `VH`. (Except, the `@NonNull` parameter probably would work actually. That would just be weird to use in Kotlin though.)

Comment: In Java, you can *only* do it the second way. You can think of the Java generic types as always having the implicit `?` because they are always nullable at the class level.

Comment: in Kotlin, shouldn't it be: class Adapter<VH: ViewHolder?> and the method: onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?)  ?

Comment: Only if you were designing the class so that it can handle a null parameter. But that's not how Adapter is supposed to work. It guarantees to subclasses that `null` will never be passed to this method, so when you subclass it you don't have to worry about checking if the holder is null.

Comment: in Kotlin, types are by default no-null, so in Kotlin both the type (in the class declaration) and also the type in the method declaration were without a question mark? And in java the default is null and therefore it adds an annotation @Nonnull in the method declartion?

Comment: In Java, it's not just that the default is nullable, but that Java provides no way to mark a generic type as non-nullable. At least not with the `@NonNull` annotation, which is actually an Android Jetpack class. Google could theoretically update it to support that after they start enforcing Java 8, but the Kotlin compiler would also have to be updated to recognize it.